# Python how to list out certain number from my list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say I have a list `my_list = [12, 23, 44, 15, 16]` I want to list out only numbers starts with `1` how can I do that?

Comment: Your second question is only slightly related to your first question and you asked it after getting two good answers to your first question. Please delete that new question from this thread, ask it as a separate question on this site, and accept the best answer below by clicking the check mark at the upper left of your question. We frown on multiple questions asked together. You also should show some of your own work on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_list = [12, 23, 44, 15, 16] 
your_list=[number for number in my_list if str(number)[0] == '1']
```

Try this. It loops through the numbers, converts them to a string, and adds them to `your_list` if they begin with `1`. Output:

```
[12, 15, 16]
```

Comment: I have a list containing `my_list = [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110]` from 100 up to 155. I want to list out even number index from 100 to 105 inclusive and odd number index from 110 to 115 inclusive and back to even number from 120 to 125 again and so on. How can I do that?

Comment: You should ask a separate question for your separate question. Then people will not have to comment answers

Comment: Sorry i edited the questions

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.startswith()` method to check if value starts with '1'

```
>>> [i for i in my_list if str(i).startswith('1')]
[12, 15, 16]
```